# How can i manipulate "ros::TimerEvent& event" from a callback time function?

Tags: c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to get data out of event, as explained in 1.4 of :
http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp_tutorials/Tutorials/Timers

But the problem is i don't know how to convert ros::time into double variable, am process further... i don't even know how to write what the obiect "event" contains using ROS_INFO, or something.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206082/how-can-i-manipulate-%22ros::timerevent&-event%22-from-a-callback-time-function?/) by [maneaflavian](https://answers.ros.org/users/22002/maneaflavian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's not `ros::time`, it's `ros::Time` (capitalizing the 'T' is necessary).

You can use the `toSec` method of a `Time` instance to get the time as a double (see the [Time Overview](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Time#Converting_Time_and_Duration_Instances) wiki).

The API for `Time` can be found [here](http://docs.ros.org/api/rostime/html/classros_1_1Time.html), while the API for its superclass `TimeBase` can be found [here](http://docs.ros.org/api/rostime/html/classros_1_1TimeBase.html).

An example of using `ROS_INFO` for the `last_real` member of a received `TimerEvent` instance *tEvent* might look like so:

```
void callback1(const ros::TimerEvent& tEvent) {
  ROS_INFO("Event last_real time: %f", tEvent.last_real.toSec());
}
```

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2015-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1